# Python - Thread with socket won't stop

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-3.x

I am programming a simple server-based chat program. I am using threads. Everything works fine, but to stop the program, I have to terminate it manually, because the thread, that is searching for new users, won't terminate, because of the socket.accep() function, which is still running. I was trying to fix that, by closing the socket, but somehow, that didn't work out. This is my code for the user search thread:

```
import socket, time
from threading import Thread
from userHandling import UserHandler

class UserSearcher(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        print("Thread: User searching is will start now!")
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self.__uH = UserHandler()
        self.__tcpListener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.__tcpListener.bind(("", 2030))
        self.__tcpListener.listen(5)
        while True:
            try:
                self.__komm, self.__tcpAddr = self.__tcpListener.accept()
                self.__tcpMsg = self.__komm.recv(1024)
                self.__uH.add(self.__tcpMsg.decode(), self.__tcpAddr[0])
            except:
                print("Searching for chat members failed! Is the system shutting down?")
                break

    def stop(self):
        self.__tcpListener.close()
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Thread: User searching will quit NOW!")
        pass
```

I don't see the mistake :/
Thanks from a python beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`socket.shutdown()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.shutdown) instead of `close()`:

```
import socket, time
from threading import Thread

class UserSearcher(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        print("Thread: User searching is will start now!")
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self.__tcpListener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.__tcpListener.bind(("", 2030))
        self.__tcpListener.listen(5)
        while True:
            try:
                self.__komm, self.__tcpAddr = self.__tcpListener.accept()
                self.__tcpMsg = self.__komm.recv(1024)
                print(self.__tcpMsg)
            except:
                print("Searching for chat members failed! Is the system shutting down?")
                break

    def stop(self):
        self.__tcpListener.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Thread: User searching will quit NOW!")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about setting a flag for the `while` loop as well:

```
class UserSearcher(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        print("Thread: User searching is will start now!")
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self.__uH = UserHandler()
        self.__tcpListener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.__tcpListener.bind(("", 2030))
        self.__tcpListener.listen(5)
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            try:
                self.__komm, self.__tcpAddr = self.__tcpListener.accept()
                self.__tcpMsg = self.__komm.recv(1024)
                self.__uH.add(self.__tcpMsg.decode(), self.__tcpAddr[0])
            except:
                print("Searching for chat members failed! Is the system shutting down?")
                break

    def stop(self):
        self.__tcpListener.close()
        self.running = False
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Thread: User searching will quit NOW!")
        pass
```